# Radio button not selected when other DOM element manipulated

Tags: javascript, html, css

The issue I am facing is happening on radio button click. 
When the input field has focus and on blur event happens there will be some field validation happening and the error message should show up below the input field.
In the following scenario:

1. focus on text input field
2. click on radio button

Error message shows up but radio button is not selected. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lajon/97w54op7/6/

See snippet below:

```js
$('input.yo').focus();

$('input.yo').focus(function() {
  $('div#message').hide();
});

$('input.yo').blur(function() {
  $('div#message').show();
  //$('div#message').delay(100).show(0);
});
```

```css
#message {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    First name:
    <input class="yo" type="text" name="fname">
    <br>
  </form>
  <div id="message">some validation error message</div>
  <form>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Possible solution is to set delay on blur

`$('p').delay(100).show(0)`

or have the space below the input field to fit the error message but this is not ideal.

I am wondering if someone could come up with more elegant fix for this issue.

Comment: Snippet added for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple, pay attention:

We have two actions trigger here:

**1#** Focus out of the input:

*That is trigged when you **press** the mouse button (or TAB, but lets think about the mouse).*

**2#** Check radio button:

*That action is trigged when you **press** the mouse buton and **release** the button, it means that the radio button will only be checked when you release the button.*

Now, just think. You are showing the `<p>` when you press out of the input (On radio button, in our case), but the radio button will be only checked when you release the button above it, but the `<p>` is already there, where the button was before. Did you see the problem?

**THE SOLITION**.

Just add a different way to show your message where it apparition can not conflict with the place of the radio button. You can style with `position`, or some thing more simple, like this way:

https://jsfiddle.net/97w54op7/9/

I hope it can help you. :)

Comment: Thanks Claudio. I am aware of this solution as well. But what if you can not move the message and by design it should be there (even if the design is not the best). I would like to know if there is something else that could be done here without changing the position of the error message.

Comment: Of course there is a way, there is always a way. You can use `mousedown` in your _jQuery_ to toggle the check on `radio button`. Doing that you dont need to **release** the click to select. Take a look here: [https://jsfiddle.net/97w54op7/10/](https://jsfiddle.net/97w54op7/10/)

Comment: Nice, that's better solution:) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use a workaround :

```
$('input.yo').blur(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { $('p').show(); }, 100);
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('input.yo').focus();
$('input.yo').focus(function() {
  $('p').hide();
});

$('input.yo').blur(function() {
  setTimeout(function() { $('p').show(); }, 100);
});
```

```css
p { 
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    First name: <input class="yo" type="text" name="fname"><br>
  </form>
  <p>some validation error message</p>
  <form>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is another solution that I already mention in my question. But it is not ideal, I would like to avoid using timeouts.